# How can do single login with spring security on two domains?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have web application and two domains for it - example.com and example.ru

example.com - for international

example.ru - for local country

My web app using spring security for authorization users but if user login through example.com on example.ru he isn't logged.

How can do that if user login through example.com or example.ru he will be logged on both domains?

PS: BTW my web application use authorization through OpenID and OAuth

Comment: The mechanism that you are looking for is called single sign on.

Comment: One problem you need to solve (I you think of implementing it by your own) is that the session id is most time stored in a cookie. But the browser assign cookies to an domain -- so you will need to handle two different sessionIds

Comment: The proper way to do this is with SSO like Kurt said.  Since you are using OpenID and OAuth though, you can also fake out the single sign on by using a HTTPClient to open the other website and then pass the cookie back to the user.  I've had to do this in environments where we mixed older Acegi and newer Spring Security applications.  It's not pretty, nor the right thing to do, but it's quick and gets the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you need a single sign on solution, [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) provides a spring security extension which includes a spring namespace so you just need to do something like:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="cloudseal">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/protected/user.do" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/protected/admin.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</security:http>

<cloudseal:sso endpoint="http://cloudseal.com" entry-point-id="cloudseal" app-id="quickstart">
    <cloudseal:keystore location="WEB-INF/keystore.jks" password="nalle123">
        <cloudseal:key name="apollo" password="nalle123" />
    </cloudseal:keystore>
    <cloudseal:metadata location="WEB-INF/idp.xml" />
</cloudseal:sso>
```

See [www.cloudseal.com/platform/spring-security-single-sign-on](http://www.cloudseal.com/platform/spring-security-single-sign-on)

Answer (score 1):

While this type of functionality is by no means trivial to achieve, it is in fact possible without modifying Spring.

The actual code is too large to post, so I'll try to outline the basic principle and leave the coding to you.

1. Extend Spring's `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`
   and implement functionality to serialize and write the
   `Authentication` object to a Session cookie with a global scope. See
   documentation for the `authentication-success-handler-ref` attribute
   in Spring's `<sec:http>` tag for more information on how to wire
   this up. (Note: If the problem were sso across multiple web apps on
   the same domain, you could of course limit the cookie scope to the
   current domain).
2. In all your web apps, add to `web.xml` a `<filter>` definition
   named `springSecurityFilterChain` and class
   `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` and a
   `<filter-mapping>` for the filter with a URL pattern of `/*` You don't have to create the actual bean, Spring Security provides a default implementation for you.
3. In all your web apps, add to `web.xml` a `<filter>` definition
   named `singleSignonAuthenticationFilterChain` with class
   `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` and a
   corresponding `<filter-mapping>` for the filter with a URL pattern
   of `/*`
4. Now you add a new bean called
   `singleSignonAuthenticationFilterChain`, which should point to a
   class that `implements Filter`. In the `doFilter()` method, check if
   there is a session attribute called `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`. If
   there is, then we are already logged in. Otherwise, take the
   serialized `Authentication` token, deserialize it and use
   `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)`
   to authenticate the user with Spring. Also remember to
   `session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT",
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext())` or the authentication will take
   place each time, which is unnecessary.

A twist to (4) is that if you find out that there is no attribute called `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`, then it could be because the user has just logged out from the current web application. In this case he must be logged out globally, so you want to remove the cookie containing the serialized authentication token in this case.

It's kind of complex to write up in a one page summary, but I hope you get the general idea.  We currently have this implemented in a complex application consisting of multiple web applications, and it works nicely.

Comment: Can you elaborate, especially steps 1 and 4?  I tried this but can't get war 2 to see the cookie from war 1

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible without modifying  spring security code. I did it sometimes ago but is very hard to maintenance

Cas is the easeiest way to this in java world.
http://www.jasig.org/cas